# How to insert QPushButton into TableView and make it view/display?

Tags: qt, delegates, qtableview, qpushbutton

Sorry to have to go this way, but this question is already available and I could ask there, but no no, need a reputation of 50 first. This give me 1.

From one of the answers:

```
QPushButton* viewButton = new QPushButton("View");
tableView->setIndexWidget(model->index(counter,2), viewButton);
```

I've tried that but the button doesn't display at all in, the code works but nothing shows in the cell. Have looked at the spinbox sample and tried a pushbutton delegate -no success

I'm using a `QStandardItemModel` to hold the data, add the model to a `QSortFilterProxyModel` (for filtering purpose) that is set to `tableView->setModel`. Display data is no problem though not the button.

Answer (score 2):

The index argument in setIndexWidget(QModelIndex const& index, QWidget*) should belong to the same model, which is set in the view. What is your variable "model" refers to? To the data holder model(which is not the model set as view's model!!!) or to the proxy-model? 
A safe approach would be to call:

```
tableView->setIndexWidget(tableView->model()->index(counter,2), viewButton);
```

Comment: I'm using QStandardItemModel *m_model ( = model in above code), that is my Q_PROPERTY ... used member variable. this m_model is set to the proxyfiltermodel, for filtering. 
The proxyFilterModel is set to the tableview->setModel.

Comment: Am I to read your answer as I'm supposed to use the index from my filterproxymodel instead of my standarditemmodel index?

Comment: Tried that and got a segmentation fault

Comment: There could be several reasons for a segfault. 
I would try to check stepwise the expression tableView->model()->index(counter,2) for validity:
assert(nullptr != tableView->model());
assert(tableView->model()->index(counter,2).isValid());
assert(nullptr != viewButton);
And a naive question: you don't use the same viewButton object for several model indexes, isn't it?

Comment: Nope, just this model index. But shall give it a test as you suggest with assert...